# UncaughtErrorEvent won't catch VerifyError (#1053)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, verifyerror

I'm loading third party swf:s, into a host swf and because I do not have control of the content I need to protect the host from going down because of errors that occur in the loaded swf:s. I have implemented the UncaughtErrorEvent handler both on the host and on the loader and this works for most runtime errors but I have problem with errors that occur when loading the swfs. E.g. if the user modifies the interface that is shared between the host and the loaded swf it will cast a "VerifyError: Error #1053" as soon as that particular interface is loaded (since it has the same namespace and class name as the one already loaded but does not match). This error is not caught and puts the host in a state where it won't load any other swfs.

Is there a way around this, or do I need to verify the bytes someway before actually loading the swf?

Comment: are you doing anything with the LoaderContext's ApplicationDomain?

Comment: Well, I've tried to load the swf's in child domains with the same result, and if I load them in completely new domains that error won't happen but it's not an option since I want them to share some classes.

Comment: i was going to suggest loading into its own domain. i don't think there is a way to exclude certain classes/packages only :/